# Run task on specific time in every timezone

Tags: c#, .net, time, timezone

Say I want to send an email notification every 6AM in every time zone
example

Run email notification job every 6AM in New York, USA,
Run email notification job every 6AM in London, UK
Run email notification job every 10AM in Tokyo, Japan

How can I do this in C#?

Note - I'm using Azure Worker Role

Comment: I downvoted your question for a few reasons : What research have you done on this subject before asking the question on Stack Overflow ? Secondly, your question is way too broad. What is your knowledge level in C#. Do you need help with scheduler or help sending the email ? Please edit your question to provide more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an application to send mails, and put this application in Task Scheduler, then set the time to run this application/send mails in Task Scheduler.

such as [image]

and check the synchronize timezones.. :)

Comment: its not C# but its an option - is this possible in Windows Azure? Im using Azure worker role as my email job

Comment: sorry, not familiar with Azure, maybe you could create another topic to ask about that...